# Why can't I use any kernel greater than 4.2?

Tags: kernel, kde

I'm pretty new in Linux. I used GNUU to download and install Linux kernels and I manually downloaded every version newer than mine (4.18.0-25-generic) none of which worked. When I turned on my PC, I was left with a blank black screen and it wasn't loading anything at all.

I read that Linux kernel >5 finally has some serious improvements with AMDs, and I'm deeply interested in that. I recently had some freeze issues, and it turned out it was something related to KWin/compositor. (not sure if this is related).

This is my OS

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.56.0
Qt Version: 5.12.2
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-25-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
Memory: 7,5 GiB of RAM
```

This is my hardware

```
sclero                      
    description: Notebook
    product: Swift SF315-41 (0000000000000000)
    vendor: Acer
    version: V1.02
    serial: NXGV7ET00175005CC27200
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: chassis=notebook family=Swift 3 sku=0000000000000000 uuid=E003CDFF-4BE2-E781-2FFC-9822EF92F3FD
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Becks_RR
       vendor: RR
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.02
       serial: NBGV511005750029DE7200
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.02
          date: 12/04/2017
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
          serial: Unknown
          slot: FP5
          size: 3344MHz
          capacity: 3600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx hw_pstate sme ssbd sev vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 - Cache
             size: 384KiB
             capacity: 384KiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 - Cache
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3 - Cache
             size: 4MiB
             capacity: 4MiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
             product: 4ATF51264HZ-2G3B1
             vendor: Micron Technology
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DIMM 0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
             product: 4ATF51264HZ-2G3B1
             vendor: Micron Technology
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DIMM 0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: IOMMU
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 0.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi ht bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 memory:e0900000-e09fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: Intel Corporation
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 03
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:48 memory:e0900000-e0903fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.7
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 memory:e0200000-e03fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 32
                serial: 98:22:ef:92:f3:fd
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.18.0-25-generic firmware=RM.4.4.1.c2-00057-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.76 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:60 memory:e0200000-e03fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:28 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:e0500000-e08fffff ioport:d0000000(size=270532608)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: c4
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
                resources: irq:50 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:e0800000-e087ffff
           *-multimedia:0
                description: Audio device
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:62 memory:e08c8000-e08cbfff
           *-generic UNCLAIMED
                description: Encryption controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:e0700000-e07fffff memory:e08cc000-e08cdfff
           *-usb:0
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.3
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:29 memory:e0600000-e06fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@1
                   logical name: usb1
                   version: 4.18
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2
                   logical name: usb2
                   version: 4.18
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-usb:1
                description: USB controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.4
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.4
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:38 memory:e0500000-e05fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@3
                   logical name: usb3
                   version: 4.18
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Video
                      product: HD WebCam
                      vendor: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@3:1
                      version: 92.26
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: USB hub
                      product: USB2.0 Hub
                      vendor: Genesys Logic, Inc.
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@3:2
                      version: 88.32
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usb:0
                         description: Mouse
                         product: G203 Prodigy Gaming Mouse
                         vendor: Logitech
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: usb@3:2.1
                         version: 7.03
                         serial: 0D8637603636
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=300mA speed=12Mbit/s
                    *-usb:1
                         description: Generic USB device
                         product: USB2.0-CRW
                         vendor: Generic
                         physical id: 2
                         bus info: usb@3:2.2
                         version: 39.60
                         serial: 20100201396000000
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                         description: Generic USB device
                         product: EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor
                         vendor: EgisTec
                         physical id: 3
                         bus info: usb@3:2.3
                         version: 10.41
                         serial: 07029CDA
                         capabilities: usb-1.10
                         configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
                    *-usb:3
                         description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                         vendor: Lite-On Technology Corp.
                         physical id: 4
                         bus info: usb@3:2.4
                         version: 0.01
                         capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
                         configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4
                   logical name: usb4
                   version: 4.18
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-multimedia:1 UNCLAIMED
                description: Multimedia controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.5
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.5
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:e0880000-e08bffff
           *-multimedia:2
                description: Audio device
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.6
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.6
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:64 memory:e08c0000-e08c7fff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 61
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 51
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:9
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 109
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.6
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:10
          description: Host bridge
          product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10a
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.7
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
```

Comment: Getting a black screen after an update is common. Boot into recovery mode and install new graphics driver for that kernel is the solution I think (hasn't happened to me yet): https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I read the guide and installed Boot-Repair (I'm currently having a dual-boot on my pc, thus I followed the second point), and that didn't work